# If-Then-Else in a Behavioral Voltage Source

Tags: ltspice

Can someone please help me modify this ISpice code so it works in LTSpice?

B1 2 33 V=V(23)-2 < 0 ? 0 : V(23)-2 > 5 ? 5 : V(23)-2

I've tried all kinds of things. Here is a simple test circuit and error code.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us your attempts? Perhaps rewrite what you have into some sort of pseudo code, so someone else can give you pointers from there? You already know it is some if-then-else statement.

Comment: Why haven't you wrapped this expression up with {}? Also, you will want "soft" transitions, if possible. Not sudden changes. I'd be looking to use something like an atan function to create rapid, but smooth transitions.

Comment: FWIW, V(1) is saying "Evaluate the constant 1 as a voltage", I suspect you meant V(V1), though be careful with that because, due to your net label V1, you have created ambiguity w/ the source which is also called V1. That ambiguity might not matter, I'm not sure how LTSpice will parse that, but I suspect it will complain during netlisting.

Answer (score 1):

That expression already works, as it is, in LTspice. The syntax is that of a ternary operator:

`condition ? expression#1 : expression#2`

which is the same as

`if( condition, expression#1, expression#2)`

And what you have there is a nested condition:

`if(a, b, if(c, d, e))`

There's no need to post any pictures since you can readily verify it yourself. In fact, I wonder why haven't you simply tried it? It's not like the computer's going to catch fire.

What [jonk](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/530078/if-then-else-in-a-behavioral-voltage-source/530090#comment1366937_530078) mentions in the comments is also true: depending on your application, the discontinuities brought by the conditional may, or may not affect the convergence. If you find that's the case, don't use a voltage source (`bv`), use a current source, instead (`bi` or `bi2`), with:

`I=<expression> Rpar=1 Cpar=10p`

Adjust as necessary.

Comment: Shouldn't `Rpar` be higher for a current source?  I usually start at `1g` for things like this.  Have I been doing it wrong all this time?

Comment: @SteKulov It depends on the purpose. Here the current source tries to emulate a voltage source, so the same expression as A needs to be in V, which means a 1 Ohm parallel resistance. But now the new voltage source has a finite resistance. Depending on the rest of the circuit, it might be an unneeded side effect. One solution would be `Rpar=1m` and `<expression>*1k`. The cap is for [convergence](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Convergence_problems%3F). If you need a parallel resistance such that the current source acts like a current source, then 1Meg...1G is the usual choice.

Comment: Ah, duh.  Of course.  Thanks, man.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need; `B1 2 33 V={if(V(23)-2<0,0,if(V(23)-2>5,5,V(23)-2))}`

Explanation;

In LTSpice the conditional operator syntax is `if(<BOOLEAN CONDITION>,<VALUE IF TRUE>,<VALUE IF FALSE>)`

Comment: Vinzent, can I talk with you via email? Ken at StairwayPress dot com

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste this into the value of a behavioral voltage source (BV):

V=if(V(V1)<0,5,if(V(V1)>5,5,V(V1)))

General syntax to copy-paste is:

V=if(V(V1)>2.5,5,0)

(not a direct answer to the question but this thread keeps popping up when I'm looking for the syntax to copy-paste, so here you go, future me.)

[image]